# Linux OCR of LCD characters

Tags: linux, ocr

I'm looking for a command line method to do optical character recognition in linux.  The main problem, however, is characters are 7-segment LCD characters.  For exampe,

[image]

I would like to use GOCR, but it gets hung up on the broken stroke of the character.  If someone knows how I can help it along, or an alternative commandline OCR that would recognize 7-segment LCD, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't until I posted this question did it occur to me that the proper description for the font type is "7-segment" not "LCD" font, and until then i had been using poor search terms on Google.  Having done a better search now, I found [SSOCR](https://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~auerswal/ssocr/) (7-segment OCR) which fits the bill perfectly.  There where other solutions on the web for 7-segment with GOCR, like shifting-overlaying image to fill the breaks, but SSOCR is pretty much straight-forward, looking at and counting the segments themselves, so it able to deal with the goofy and restricted character-set of 7-segment displays.